# How to implement Authentication as a Web Service (Symfony2, REST)

Tags: rest, symfony, service, authentication

I hope someone could help with this:

I am working on a php project and I need to implement the authentication of the application as a Service. I need to do something like Google where offers a Service to login in other applications using Google's Authentication Service (for example trello.com allows visitors to login with their google account).

I would like to clarify my mind, because I have no idea how to start it. I am using Symfony2 framework and I'm trying to work RESTFully, but basically what I need is just an idea of what I have to do or investigate to carry this out.

Comment: Do you want to let users authenticate with their Google/FB/whatever account in your application? Or do you want, others can use your REST-API with authentication?

Comment: I want others can use my REST-API with authentication. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the symfony Ecosystem is big, take a look at the [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) for creating the API. Then there is the [NelmioApiDocBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle) for easy documentation of your REST-API. For authenticating you should consider OAuth, so take a look at the [FOSOAuthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle). With all three combined you can create a great API.

Also read this article, about [REST APIs with Symfony2: The Right Way](http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm gonna read the article and investigate about the bundles you mentioned.