# Creating WebService for Symfony2 application

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a Symfony2 with FOSUserBundle.

How the best way to create a WebService for a remote application?

There are any bundle that will handle the authentication?

I was thinking to create an Controler for the API, and check the `login/password` with https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/696
That's a good idea?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18820547/1406096

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should then consider using [FOSOAuthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle).

Here are some useful links on how to implement it,

- [The Bundle's documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)
- [Setting Up OAuth2 With Symfony2 Using FOSOAuthServerBundle](http://blog.tankist.de/blog/2013/07/17/oauth2-explained-part-2-setting-up-oauth2-with-symfony2-using-fosoauthserverbundle/)
- [How to implement FosOAuthServerBundle to secure an REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259190/how-to-implement-fosoauthserverbundle-to-secure-an-rest-api#21264949)